# Print statement is not displaying my output

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

For my homework, I am working on a method that draws a polynomial curve. I started displaying a 20x20 Cartesian plan, but for some reason the print statements are not displayed. Could someone help me figure out the problem? Thank you

```
 public class PolynomialCurves{
      public static void main (String[] args) {

        double[] line = {1.0, 2};
        double lineThickness = 1;

        drawCurve(line, lineThickness, '$');
      }


    // A method that draws the graph of a polynomial curve

      public static void drawCurve(double[] coefficient, double thickness, char symbol) {

        // Loop that counts the y position

        for (int y = 20; y >= 0; y--) {

          if (y == 10) {

          // Loop that counts the x position

            for (int x = 0; x < 21; x++) {

              if (x == 10) {

                System.out.print('+');
              }

              else if (x == 20) {

              System.out.print('>');
              }

              else {
              System.out.print('-');
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the line `for (int y = 20; y <= 0; y--)` and pay attention to the logic..

Comment: Remember that in `for(init, condition, increment)` condition decides if loop should *iterate* (execute code from its body). If it is true it will iterate, it not it will stop iteration. When `y=20` what boolean value will you get at `y<=20`?

Comment: Also your y-loop contains only `if(y==10){...}` which means that for y other than 10 it will not do anything. That kind of defeats purpose of having that loop.

Comment: Wow I accidentally mistaken >= for <=. Thanks

Comment: Keep it up @Maya, you're doing great!

Comment: @Pshemo I suspect Maya's intention is to replace `if(x==10)` with something more sophisticated once they get the printing logic sorted out.

Comment: Correct.  The program is a work in progress, none of the parameters are even being used yet.  No reason to critique too much..

Comment: @Pshemo At y == 10, there would be a '+' to represent the origin while at y != 10 , the method would print '-'.

Comment: @Maya OK, that is what you *want* to do, but currently your `else` block is related to `if (x == 10)`, not `if (y == 10)`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You may be right but notice I was talking about earlier `if`, one handling `y` not `x`.

Comment: @Pshemo, oh, I'm sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough.  Yeah, having two `if` statements does seem a bit overkill.  Apologies for my response to your earlier comment.

Comment: @Pshemo The if (y == 0) would be use later on to display the y axis

Comment: @MikeChristensen Could you help me with displaying the y axis? I know that you need 3 if statements for '|' , '^' and "(empty space)"